# Uniform superposition of states with one qubit set to $|1\rangle$ and others to $|0\rangle$

Tags: quantum-state, entanglement, circuit-construction

I am wondering what a circuit should look like if I want to prepare the state of the following form:
$$
|0\rangle^{\otimes n} \mapsto \dfrac{
|1000\ldots0\rangle +
|0100\ldots0\rangle +
|0010\ldots0\rangle +
\ldots + 
|00\ldots001\rangle
}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
Is this something well-known and trivial?

**ANSWER**

Apparently, this question was asked [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4350/general-construction-of-w-n-state).

The Q# realization is provided in katas 15-17 [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/Superposition/ReferenceImplementation.qs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your state is a generalization of so-called [W-state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_state).

[Here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8766/is-it-possible-to-have-entanglement-between-more-than-two-qubits/8768#8768) is a implementation of the state for three qubits.

You can also use method described in paper [Transformation of quantum states using uniformly controlled rotations](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0407010) for preparing W-state with any qubits you want.
When you use this method, set probability of states $|10\dots0 \rangle$, $|01\dots 0\rangle$,...$|00\dots1 \rangle$ to $\frac{1}{n}$ and probability of other states to zero.